# How to sort by popularity in magento 2 product list?

Tags: magento-2.1, product-sorting

I want to sort products by popularity and discount(high to low).

How can I achieve?

Comment: Which term you refer when you say popularity? Is it most viewed, bestseller or sort accouding to custom order ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use native table for select popularity and discount:

`report_viewed_product_index` - products popularity `(SUM(index_id) GROUP BY product_id)`

`catalog_product_index_price` - `discount = final_price - price`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this module and use funtional part accordingly.
https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-catalog-sortby